# When does a certain limit exist?

Tags: limits

Let $c >0$ be a constant. I am interested in$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{cn}{2\log_2{n}}+1}}  \left( \frac{2}{\pi} \right)^{\frac{cn}{2\log_2{n}}} \sum_{w=1}^n \frac{(2ne)^w}{w^{\frac{cn}{2\log_2{n}}}w^w}.$$

What is the minimum $c$ for which this limit exists?  I can see that the limit is $0$ for large $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w=nx$, and $k = \log_e 2$. Let 
$$f(x)=\frac{(2ne)^{nx}}{(nx)^{cnk/(2\ln n)}(nx)^{nx}}$$
I want to show $f(x)$ has just two local maxima in $[0,1]$, which are at $0$ and $1$.  Let 
$$g(x)=\frac1n\ln f(x)=x\ln(2ne)-\frac{ck}{2\ln n}\ln nx-x\ln nx\\
\frac{dg}{dx}=\ln(2ne)-\frac{ck}{2x\ln n}-\ln nx - 1=k-\ln x-\frac{ck}{2x\ln n}\\
\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}=\frac{ck}{2x^2\ln n}-\frac1x\\=0 \text{ at }x=ck/(2\ln n)$$

$g'(x)$ is negative near $x=0$, approaches $k>0$ when $x=1$ and $n$ is large, and has at most one turning point.  So $g'(x)=0$ for at most one value of $x$ when $n$ is large.  So $g(x)$ has no local maxima on $(0,1)$.
The sum is bounded between $f(1/n)+f(1)$ and $n(f(1/n)+f(1))= n(2ne+(2e2^{-c/2})^n)$.  $nf(1/n)$, multiplied by the power of $2/\pi$, approaches zero.  We need $(2e2^{-c/2})^n$ to be less than $1$, otherwise it dominates the other factors.  That happens when $c>log_2(4e^2)$